# Menuitem tooltip in javafx2

Tags: javafx-2

There are two questions in javafx2..

1. How to set tooltip for the menuitem
2. How to set size (width) for the menu item

Kindly let me know if you have the answer..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to both questions direct to the class [CustomMenuItem](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html), which wraps an arbitrary Node and puts it into a menu.
For example, the following creates a rectangle within a menu with a certain width, height and ToolTip:

```
public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Group root = new Group();

    final Menu menu1 = new Menu("File");
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    menuBar.getMenus().add(menu1);

    MenuItem menu12 = new MenuItem("Open");

    menu1.getItems().add(menu12);

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.setHeight(100);
    rect.setWidth(100);

    Tooltip t = new Tooltip("A Rectangle ToolTip");
    Tooltip.install(rect, t);

    CustomMenuItem customMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(rect);
    customMenuItem.setHideOnClick(false);

    menu1.getItems().add(customMenuItem);

    root.getChildren().add(menuBar);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,600);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
  }
```

Comment: Any idea why accelerators don't work with `CustomMenuItem`? Question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43368990/451962

Answer (score 3):

### 1- Installing a Tooltip on a MenuItem

```
Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip("This is a tooltip");
```

As you know already, **to bind a Tooltip** to a JavaFX graphical object `foo`:

```
Tooltip.install(foo, tooltip);
```

This static utility **requires the provided object to extend Node**, and a **MenuItem does not**.

However its CustomMenuItem subclass can solve your issue. Quoted directly from the [CustomMenuItem Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html):

> A MenuItem that allows for arbitrary nodes to be embedded within it, by assigning a Node to the content property. CustomMenuItem attempts to make arbitrary nodes appear more natural in the Menu. For example, you automatically get hover highlighting when the user hovers their mouse over the node (or navigates to it using keyboard or other alternate means).

For example, to **create a CustomMenuItem** that looks and behave exactly like a regular MenuItem:

```
CustomMenuItem openMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(new Label("Open"));
```

You can then **attach your Tooltip to its wrapped content** (which is a Node):

```
Tooltip.install(openMenuItem.getContent(), tooltip);
```

If you intend to use CustomMenuItem with other types of nodes, do get a look to the [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html), in particular to the bit about `setHideOnClick`,  but this is off-topic.

### 2- Resizing a MenuItem

You can't resize a MenuItem but you can use a Node that allow it and, again, **wrap it in a CustomMenuItem**:

```
Label closeLabel = new Label("Close");
closeLabel.setPrefWidth(400); // Overly large menu item
CustomMenuItem closeMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(closeLabel);
```