# How do I add a tooltip to a CheckMenuItem?

Tags: java, javafx, java-8

How do you add a `Tooltip` to a `CheckMenuItem`; I was able to add a graphic node to it, and set the `Tooltip` to the graphic node, but that is not what I want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menuitem tooltip in javafx2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927559/menuitem-tooltip-in-javafx2)

Comment: I don’t think a this will help me because a CheckMenuItem has other features I need.

Comment: It will help you, I promise. You can put a `CheckBox` within the `CustomMenuItem` the other answer talks about.